# Color coded table plot based on the values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe df containing string values

a b c d

b c d a

I would like to produce a pdf plot based on the data in the df, with 4 cols and 2 rows, where each cell in the table plot has a color depending on the value in the df, a=blue, b=red, c=yellow, d=green.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZXZ2.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "table" you mean a `plt.table` or a subplot grid? I think you would benefit from describing much more in detail the desired output and also what other resources have not helped you achieve what you want.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a picture of what I am looking for :)

Comment: I would probably map the characters to numbers first, then plot an `imshow` plot of the data. You will need a custom colormap with the 4 colors in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
from matplotlib import colors as c

color_map = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3, 'd':4}
cMap = c.ListedColormap(['g','b','y','r'])
df = df.replace(color_map)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(df,cmap=cMap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And If you want to remove the `ticks`, add `plt.xticks([])` and `plt.yticks([])`